# overlaps issue on Access user trusted tool text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: overlap]

If I try to see my notification in my Activity, the notification and Access user trusted tool text overlaps. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. We launched new topbar so I think this should be fixed now, right?

Comment: yeah exactly thank you.